# Update child firebase and delete child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
public class CowDet extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


private EditText postTitleEdit;
private EditText postTextEdit;
private TextView key1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cow_det);

    postTextEdit = findViewById(R.id.postTextEdit);
    postTitleEdit = findViewById(R.id.postTitleEdit);
    key1 = findViewById(R.id.key1);



    postTitleEdit.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
    postTextEdit.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("desc"));

    String key = getIntent().getExtras().get("key").toString();
    key1.setText(key);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Mblog").child(key);
}

public void deleteButton(View view){

    String key = databaseReference.child("Mblog").push().getKey();
    databaseReference.child("Mblog").child(key).removeValue();
    startActivity(new Intent(CowDet.this, PostListActivity.class));
    finish();
}

public void update_button(View view){
    String key = databaseReference.child("Mblog").push().getKey();
    databaseReference.child("Mblog").child(key).setValue(postTitleEdit.getText().toString());
    databaseReference.child("Mblog").child(key).setValue(postTextEdit.getText().toString());
    startActivity(new Intent(CowDet.this, PostListActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

}

Where when I try to update something on my firebase db is just creating a new child with the "Mblog" name

[image]

I'm pretty sure I'm not referencing my key correctly, but I've tried in many ways but can't really solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your call `push()` Firebase generates a new unique key, so this line in your `deleteButton` and `update_button` functions creates those new keys you see:

```
String key = databaseReference.child("Mblog").push().getKey();
```

To delete or update an existing child you need to know its key, and then pass that into the call like this:

```
String key = "the known key of the node to delete";
databaseReference.child("Mblog").child(key).removeValue();
```

You'll typically capture the key when you first create the node, when you read the nodes from the database, or when you pass it from the list view to a detail view. From there you need to pass it along, until it gets to your `deleteButton` and `update_button` functions, which can then use it.